# OneDrive folder keeps moving to bottom of Finder Favorites sidebar

Tags: macos, finder, sidebar

In my favorites sidebar, my OneDrive Folder keeps moving back at the bottom of the favorite list each time I reboot.

Can I make sure that it remains on top of my list of favorites on the sidebar of my Finder?

Answer (score 4):

This was bugging me as well, until I noticed one of my Macs didn't move it to the bottom. The difference? On that Mac, OneDrive was installed via the App Store, whereas the others were downloaded from the OneDrive web site.

So I uninstalled OneDrive from those affected Macs, reinstalled it from the App Store, and made sure I re-enabled the Finder Extension. Now after a restart, the OneDrive folder stays where I placed it in the Favorites side bar! :)

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive's icon is dynamically added by the app itself, you might be able to get to behave by turning the feature off, restarting and turning the feature back on. Otherwise, its in the way Microsoft are managing the icon. Dropbox seems to handle this by using a real folder instead of a virtual one, and Finder can therefore manage the sidebar item correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The Google Drive folder also remains on top. Only OneDrive keeps going down.

Comment: Which feature (that I should turn off and back on again) are you referring to?